# Accessing translation workbench via apex?

Tags: translation-workbench

Where does salesforce store translation workbench details ? Are they accessible via apex? I tried once, I changed the email field of Account through translation workbench to myEmail. Can I retrieve information where it is stored?

Answer (score 2):

translation workbench works on the users language. if u have added myEmail for English then that will be the label visible to u on ur Account record itself. the idea is that on the object the label remains the same, however depending on the users language the label varies when you view the record. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Can this information be accessed via apex?

Answer (score 1):

Via apex u will be accessing the Api name of the field. so that remains the same irrespective of the language